# Break Column while printing HTML table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a HTML table with 20 Columns, My requirement was the Column header should repeat on every page & if Columns doesn't fit in 1 page they should move to next page.

I have achieved the first part i.e. Header on same page but don't know how to do column break???

Have to do it on IE8+

Update : Missed the part that the requirement is related to print. While printing the table I am facing this issue.... ooooops :P

Comment: have you tried something?plz share it here

Comment: jQuery DataTables can be used for showing table, as it manages search, sort, pagination, etc functionality : http://datatables.net

Comment: Hi, sorry missed 1 thing that I need to cater the problem while I am printing that HTML Table

Answer (score 0):

If you are prepared to consider a jQuery plugin, then I would recommend [datatables](http://datatables.net/), which handles pagination, though row-wise, not column-wise.

However, the plugin's `fnSetColumnVis()` command allows columns to be hidden/shown and could be used to achieve what you call a "column break" effect.

You would need to write a function that toggles between, for example :

- showing columns 2 to 10 and hiding columns 11 to 20
- hiding columns 2 to 10 and showing columns 11 to 20

to achieve a kind of column-wise pagination.